# Error Retrieving Topic Messages in kafka-topics-ui (HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type)

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper

I just started using Kafka and wants to use [`kafka-topics-ui`](https://github.com/Landoop/kafka-topics-ui) to look at the various topics that I have.

`docker-compomse.yml` shown below is used to quickly set up `zookeeper`, `kafka`, `kafka-topics-ui`, including `schema-registry` and `rest-proxy`.

**Problem:** On loading the `kafka-topics-ui` website at `localhost:8000`, when we click on one of the topics, the loading progress bar animates without stopping, and none of the topic's messages appear!

On looking at the browser JS console, we see that there has been an *HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type* error from performing a POST request:

**Errors from JS Console**

```
angular.js:12587 POST http://localhost:8000/api/kafka-rest-proxy/consumers/kafka_topics_ui_avro_2018-12-02-03-10-39-256 415 (Unsupported Media Type)
(anonymous) @ angular.js:12587
p @ angular.js:12332
(anonymous) @ angular.js:12084
(anonymous) @ angular.js:16832
$digest @ angular.js:17971
$apply @ angular.js:18269
(anonymous) @ angular.js:26999
hg @ angular.js:3734
d @ angular.js:3722

angular.js:14525 HTTP ERROR:  Failed at method [POST] [/api/kafka-rest-proxy/consumers/kafka_topics_ui_avro_2018-12-02-03-10-39-256] with error: 
{"data":{"error_code":415,"message":"HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type"},"status":415,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"/api/kafka-rest-proxy/consumers/kafka_topics_ui_avro_2018-12-02-03-10-39-256","data":"{\"name\": \"kafka-topics-ui-avro\", \"format\": \"avro\", \"auto.offset.reset\": \"earliest\", \"auto.commit.enable\": \"false\"}","dataType":"json","headers":{"Content-Type":"application/vnd.kafka.v2+json","Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"Unsupported Media Type"} 
DATA SENT: {"name": "kafka-topics-ui-avro", "format": "avro", "auto.offset.reset": "earliest", "auto.commit.enable": "false"}
```

What went wrong and how can we fix this?

**docker-compomse.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:

zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
    - "2181:2181"

kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
    - "9092:9092"
    - "9999:9999"
    environment:
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 127.0.0.1
    KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "orders:1:1,trades:1:1"
    KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    JMX_PORT: 9999
    depends_on:
    - zookeeper

schema-registry:
    image: confluent/schema-registry:latest
    ports:
    - 8081:8081
    links:
    - zookeeper
    - kafka
    depends_on:
    - zookeeper
    - kafka

rest-proxy:
    image: confluent/rest-proxy:latest
    ports:
    - 8082:8082
    links:
    - zookeeper
    - kafka
    - schema-registry
    depends_on:
    - zookeeper
    - kafka
    - schema-registry

kafka-topics-ui:
    image: landoop/kafka-topics-ui
    environment:
    # yes localhost as its a client side app outsite of the docker network on your host
    - KAFKA_REST_PROXY_URL=http://rest-proxy:8082
    - PROXY=true
    ports:
    - 8000:8000
    links:
    - rest-proxy
    depends_on:
    - rest-proxy
```

Comment: Just curious why you're using confluent images for other things, but not actually Kafka and Zookeeper?

Comment: Also, the `confluentinc/` images are the newer, and maintained ones.

Comment: @cricket_007 I copied the zookeeper and kafka code from a gist that uses the non-confluent images, and the rest of the docker-compose from another more updated one. I tried updating my `docker-compose.yml` to use `confluent/zookeeper` and `confluent/kafka` and recreated the containers but the same error persists on the POST request

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the error/solution, but I would guess it's CORS related, or you're using some old `confluent/` docker images...

In any case, I do have a suggestion for you.

Landoop offers an all-in-one packaged container called `fast-data-dev` which includes all these components you would want (plus some)

On Linux host,

> ```
> docker run --rm --net=host landoop/fast-data-dev
> ```
>
> That's it. Visit http://localhost:3030 to get into the fast-data-dev
>   environment

**More information** (for example, if you aren't running on Linux): https://github.com/Landoop/fast-data-dev

Comment: Thats a great resource! Is there a working `docker-compose.yml` alternative that does the same thing, so that it is easier to remove the components that are not (yet) needed?

Comment: You can't remove the components from it, but the overhead of having them isn't really a problem, in my opinion. If you still want individual container, you can use https://github.com/simplesteph/kafka-stack-docker-compose/blob/master/full-stack.yml